# Instagram API graph stories

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram-graph-api

First I auth my user, which has role `instagram Test Users`, got access token by doint request to `https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token` Follow [Getting Started](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/getting-started) guide.

Make a request to get user data `https://graph.instagram.com/me?fields=username&access_token={{ACCESS_TOKEN}}`

Everything OK, got 200 status and data.

Now tried to follow [API Stories Docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-user/stories/)
make a request to: `https://graph.facebook.com/{{IG_ID}}/stories?access_token={{ACCESS_TOKEN}}` (IG_ID is the ID I got from user data request) but doesn't work return invalid access token

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "Invalid OAuth access token - Cannot parse access token",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 190,
        "fbtrace_id": "{ID}" //im not sure if important to hide
    }
}
```

Now tried to use Explorer Api Graph (Tools->Explorer) I generate an access token (this token is generated with Facebook, not instagram), use this token and the ID (/me in Explorer API) in previous request and the response is:

```
//https://graph.facebook.com/{{ID}}/stories?access_token={{TOKEN}}
{
    "error": {
        "message": "(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (stories) on node type (User)",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 100,
        "fbtrace_id": "{ID}"
    }
}
```

Maybe I'm misunderstanding the guide, anyone have worked with API?

Hmmm... Does API works with private/public accounts? Or only if account is Business/Content Creator might use this?

Comment: The Instagram Graph API is for business/creator accounts; for normal user accounts, there is only the Instagram Basic Display API (and that doesn't allow for any publishing.)

Comment: I don't think he wants to publish anything, just get a list of current stories.

Comment: Yes, just 'read'. I though it was possible but i dont think so... Only scrapping website :/